# PHP Zip module install but still I am getting error

Tags: wordpress

I have godaddy hosting. I install the php zip module through php pear packages. 
But Still I am getting this error.
Oops, Unyson Backup requires PHP Zip module but it is not enabled on your server. If you are not familiar with PHP Zip module, please contact your hosting provider.
I have install the zip through php pear.

While on php pear packages i am having this message.
You will need to add “/home/g45h9xclhwaz/php” to the include path. You can do this by adding the following code to your script:

```
ini_set("include_path", '/home/g45h9xclhwaz/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );
```

I Don't Know where to install  in the script.

Comment: Do you have access to your cPanel?

Comment: Yes I have access to cpanel and from cpanel I have install the zip

Comment: Did you install it following these instructions? https://uniib84584.i.lithium.com/community/image/serverpage/image-id/386i30025F67537E49BB/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999 https://uniib84584.i.lithium.com/community/image/serverpage/image-id/387i7A42EF097AAC20C7/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

Comment: No i have not followd this In php pear package i type zip and clicked on go to, installed it.

Comment: You need to install them in a cPanel way...just like in the pictures

Comment: ok let me try..

Comment: Glad to help @Nauman